# R: data.table function row insert fails

Tags: r, function, data.table

I'm struggling since a few hours with following task:

I've got a data table:

```
dt1 <- data.table(a = c(1:4), b = c(2:5), c= c(5:8))
```

and a function:

```
myfun <- function(a, b, c) {
  r <- 30

  dt2 <- data.table(temp_int = seq(-10,50, by = 0.05))
  dt2[, d   := a * temp_int]
  dt2[, e   := b / temp_int]
  dt2[, f   := c + temp_int]
  dt2[, g   := d - e - f]
  # return row where g nearest to 0
  dt2[g == min(abs(g)), ]
}
```

If I test the function with test values everything is fine an I get a plausible and expected answer.

But when I try to call the function as follows:

```
dt1[, c('d','e','f','g') := myfun(a,b,c)]
```

I get error messages like:

```
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In a * temp_int :
   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In b/temp_int :
   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

and the data table looks as follows:

```
> dt1
   a b c    d    e  f   g
1: 1 2 5 -0.5 -1.5 -8 6.5
2: 2 3 6 -0.5 -1.5 -8 6.5
3: 3 4 7 -0.5 -1.5 -8 6.5
4: 4 5 8 -0.5 -1.5 -8 6.5
```

so basically every row is filled with the same result (from the first calculation). I have some trouble understanding the problem. Do I have to convert the result from a data table before returning it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please feel free to take a [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site, and if you need additional help with the site, check [this](//stackoverflow.com/help) out. Oh, and if you ever run into issues that the help page doesn't cover, feel free to ask on [meta](//meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: You pass vectors of a, b, c values to the function. Test what the function returns outside the data.table if you pass it vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. After that and a good night sleep I finally know where I got the error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the function and passing the vectors from the data table I needed to slightly modify the call to:

```
dt1[, c('d','e','f','g') := myfun(a,b,c), by = 1:nrow(dt1)]
```

basically calling the function row by row.

Are there any suggestions how to speed things up? Is it possible? (real data and calculation are somewhat bigger and more complex)